# How to add variable using mytheme_preprocess_field and print using twig template?

Tags: 8, theming, entities, hooks

We have a content type Article that has two custom fields: `field_header` and `field_link`. When `field_header` is not populated, we want to perform validation in twig template to add a CSS class. When we tried to set a custom variable using `$variables['myVariable'] = TRUE` and try to print the value in the twig template, it is returning a `NULL` value.

How can I create a custom variable using `mytheme_preprocess_field()` hook and use it in the twig template?

mytheme.theme

```
function mytheme_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  if($element['#field_name'] == 'field_header') {
    if($element['#items']->first()->isEmpty()) {
      $variables['myVariable'] = TRUE;
    }
  }
}
```

node--article.html.twig

```
<div>
  {{ kint(myVariable) }} // Returns NULL everytime.

  {% if myVariable %}
    // If not empty, do something.
  {% else %}
    // If empty, do something else. 
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables in a template are scoped - what you add in `hook_preprocess_field` will only be available in *field.html.twig* and its derivatives, not *node.html.twig* etc.

You can implement the same logic in the node preprocess:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['node']->hasField('field_header') && $variables['node']->field_header->isEmpty()) {
    $variables['myVariable'] = TRUE;
  }
}
```

Comment: that highlighted my problem, can't believe i did not see. making the change solved the problem once i converted to `hook_preprocess_node`